# why do we need add annotation @Transactional in springdata for update function?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

why do we need add annotation @Transactional in Springdata for update function while we dont need it for create, remove, delete?

Below is an example.

```
@Service
public class PersonService
{
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Transactional
    public int updateEmail(String email,Integer id)
    {
        return personRepository.updateEmail(email, id);
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the official [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/#transactions):

> CRUD methods on repository instances are transactional by default. For reading operations the transaction configuration readOnly flag is set to true, all others are configured with a plain @Transactional so that default transaction configuration applies.

So, we can conclude that all default methods for data manipulation (e.g. `delete`, `deleteAll`, `save` etc.) use `@Transactional` by default. And we can look at `JpaRepository` default implementation [`SimpleJpaRepository`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java) to confirm that. Next thing is when you write your own methods for data manipulation (and as I can see you create a method to update an email for Person class) they are `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` by default hence such methods cannot anyhow affect the existing data. So that's why we need to annotate them with `@Transactional` annotation.